# default route '/' is still listed on top of artisan route:list

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I have a project that uses sub-domains.

Now, after following the **RouteServiceProvider** on how they map the Routes, I finally made a custom RouteServiceProvider for my Subdomains named **SubdomainRouteServiceProvider**.

Now, I also edited the **config/app.php** and set the **SubdomainRouteServiceProvider** ahead of **RouteServiceProvider** as shown below.

```
    App\Providers\SubdomainRoutesServiceProvider::class,


    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

Now when I typed in the **artisan:route-list** this shows.

```
|                         | GET|HEAD | / | Closure | web    |
| company-one.sample.test | GET|HEAD | / | Closure | web    |
```

Is there any thing I need to customize?
Or any thing missing?

any help would be great!

**Update!!** Added Route Files

```
/*
 * Folder: app/Subdomain/CompanyOne/routes/web.php
 */
Route::domain('company-one.sample.test')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('CompanyOne . views . welcome');
    });
});


/*
 * Folder: routes/web.php
 */
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Can you please show us what your Routes `routes/web` file looks like?

Comment: @hinteractive02 yes, updated it

Comment: @hinteractive02 have you tried having that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I was just fooled by looking at the **route:list**.

when I typed the actual route it shows the page.